# Creating web service client in Eclipse and NetBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, netbeans

I have web service created using `.NET C#`. I have generated web service using both `NetBeans` and `Eclipse` wizzards. In both cases web service clients are running but both clients has very different implementation. In `NetBeans` case i got to use many jar libraries like:

```
jax-qname.jar,
jaxrpc-api.jar,
jaxrpc-impl.jar,
jaxrpc-spi.jar 
and others.
```

In Eclipse case I'm pushed to use less libs like:

```
jaxrpc.jar,
javax.wsdl_1.6.2.v201012040545.jar,
commons-discovery-0.2.jar,
org.apache.commons.logging_1.1.1.v201101211721.jar,
saaj.jar
```

For me Eclipse client looks nicer - it has less code generated and requires less libs. But which one is better? What kind of technologies the are using? And finally - can I create web service client without using any third party libs?

Comment: 3rd solution: generate the client with a reproducible process, like a Maven build

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28899338/1582089 with maven or C:\>wsimport -keep -verbose http://localhost:8080/ws/server?wsdl