# Generated sources from WSDL using WSDL2Java generates classes with deprecated API javax xml ws on java 11

Tags: java, wsdl, java-11, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

On my project I am using java 11.

based on a WSDL file, i generate code classes using `cxf-codegen-plugin` maven plugin.
the classes generated, use `javax.xml.ws.*` and other APIs on java 11.

example :

one of the generated Classes `extends Service`   which is from `javax.xml.ws.Service` this library is not deprecated on java 11, but i have a compatibility error.

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JAXP09020005: The specified argument 'classpath:/schemas/wsdl' (case sensitive) for 'setRewritePrefix' is not valid.
    at java.xml/javax.xml.catalog.CatalogMessages.reportIAE(CatalogMessages.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/javax.xml.catalog.BaseEntry.verifyURI(BaseEntry.java:231) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/javax.xml.catalog.RewriteSystem.setRewritePrefix(RewriteSystem.java:65) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/javax.xml.catalog.RewriteSystem.<init>(RewriteSystem.java:47) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/javax.xml.catalog.CatalogReader.startElement(CatalogReader.java:190) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2708) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:276) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/javax.xml.catalog.CatalogImpl.parse(CatalogImpl.java:295) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/javax.xml.catalog.CatalogImpl.load(CatalogImpl.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/javax.xml.catalog.CatalogManager.catalog(CatalogManager.java:73) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/javax.xml.catalog.CatalogManager.catalogResolver(CatalogManager.java:119) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlCatalogUtil.createCatalogResolver(XmlCatalogUtil.java:125) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlCatalogUtil.createDefaultCatalogResolver(XmlCatalogUtil.java:105) ~[jaxws-rt-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

how can i overcome this compatibility error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with the `cxf-codegen-plugin 3.3.5` and the solution was to use cxf's dependencies instead of `com.sun.xml.ws` (or any other rt).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried also to remove com.sun.xml.ws dependency and use org.apache.cfx V.3.4.2. It worked for me. (with Java11)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, try to update your cxf-codegen-plugin to version 3.3.2

Comment: For another question with potentially more info about this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857820/cxf-codegen-maven-plugin-doesnt-work-openjdk-11