# No wsgen in JDK 17

Tags: java, java-ee-8, wsgen

I have JDK 17 and JDK 1.8 on my Windows PC. Why does JDK 17 not contain wsgen.exe in the bin directory while JDK 1.8 contains it? How can I build web applications without wsgen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does JDK 17 not contain wsgen.exe in the bin directory while JDK 1.8 contains it?

Because JEP 320 has [removed](https://openjdk.org/jeps/320) 9 modules from Java 11, removing alongside tools such as `wsgen` and `wsimport` (from `jdk.xml.ws`).

> How can I build web applications without wsgen?

Do you mean *how to build*? or how to generate/scaffold some code? for building, there are different tools, but for whatever you used `wsgen`, you could probably refer to maven plugins, some of which you can find [here](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/).

You may also find useful [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892528/migration-jaxws-application-from-java-8-to-java-11) thread.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of `wsgen.bat` and `wsgen.sh` (not `wsgen.exe`), look in the Jakarta XML Web Services implementation release, which is part of Project Metro from Eclipse.

Steps:

1. Go to the Jakarta XML Web Services [home page](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/metro-jax-ws/) and click on the download link (or click [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-ri/4.0.0/jaxws-ri-4.0.0.zip) for a direct download). The link is in the sentence containing the text "... available for download...", if you can't spot it.
2. Unzip the resulting `jaxws-ri-4.0.0.zip` file.
3. Look in the `bin` directory where you will find `.bat` scripts for Windows and `.sh` for Linux.

[image]

---

If you need a different version, see the Maven listing here: [com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-ri](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-ri/).