# How to generate SOAP stubs in Java?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

It's the first I am working with `SOAP` interface.

I have [WSDL](https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebService.asmx?WSDL) that I suppose to generate stub classes from.

I use `axistools-maven-plugin` but not all classes were generated. For instance, `ConnectWithToken` wasn't present into generated stubs.

My `pom.xml` `plugins` section:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${axis.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <urls>
        <url>https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebService.asmx?WSDL</url>
      </urls>
      <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
      <subPackageByFileName>true</subPackageByFileName>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <allElements>true</allElements>
      <indentSize>4</indentSize>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Is it the way for me to generate all classes specified into `wsdl` using above plugin?

Comment: check from here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338196/how-to-generate-classes-from-wsdl-using-maven-and-wsimport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to change SOAP class generator provider. [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338196/how-to-generate-classes-from-wsdl-using-maven-and-wsimport) helped a lot but I had to adopt solution based on the `jaxws-maven-plugin` plugin documentation and project.

`pom.xml` dependencies section:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

`pom.xml` build section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-source-by-wsdl</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                            <wsdlUrls>
                                <wsdlUrl>https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebService.asmx?WSDL</wsdlUrl>
                            </wsdlUrls>
                            <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```