# How I get the answer from a Web Service with Java in Netbeans?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans

I want to consume this Web Service:
https://celcer.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/AutorizacionComprobantesOffline?wsdl

The documentation about the Web Service say that I have to send an xml document as a parameter and the web service will return and XML object.

I've already tried in Netbeans creating a new class --> web service client--> wsdl and I got this:

[image: Ref Image]

A package named autorizacion.ws.sri.gob.ec and a bunch of classes with him.
I'd like to know how can I create a constructor for those classes so I can send XML file as parameter?
And how can I use the XML object to see the answers?

Thank you for your help I've been trying this for two weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In soap-based web service you need to generate java artifact/client. You have multiple options to generate it, Kindly follow the link to get more detail

- [How do you convert WSDLs to Java classes using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460571/how-do-you-convert-wsdls-to-java-classes-using-eclipse)
- [How to generate classes from wsdl using Maven and wsimport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338196/how-to-generate-classes-from-wsdl-using-maven-and-wsimport)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll try it