# wsimport generation with conflicting names

Tags: java, maven, wsimport

I used the maven plugins from the answer in [How to generate classes from wsdl using Maven and wsimport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338196/how-to-generate-classes-from-wsdl-using-maven-and-wsimport),
but I get some of the following errors (sanitized because work):

The wsdl consists of multiple 'messages' defined as follows:

```
<wsdl:message name="Name_in">
    <wsdl:part element="xx:CommonName" name="NameReqType"/>
  </wsdl:message>
```

Where:

- 'Name' is an object name
- 'xx' is the type, i.e. xlmns:xx
- 'CommonName' is the name used by every primary object

`[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "com.package.CommonName" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict. [ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "ServiceClass" is generated from here.`

There are a lot of related xsd's in a parallel folder as well, resulting in the following

```
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
```

Any help would be appreciated, I haven't worked with wsimport much.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you submit a question, try to ensure that we can replicate your problem. You are following one existing answer but you are not mention what it is different at your setup or code that could generate those errors. Please, edit it again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added some more information, but unfortunately I can't copy directly from the WSDL, one, because its proprietary(ish?), and two, its 19000 lines long